# PHP convert separate date and time strings into single datetime

Tags: php, datetime, date-conversion

I have two separate strings for date and time formatted something like: `14/04/2014` and `01:15 PM`

I would like to convert these to a datetime formatted as `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Any idea how I go about this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i A', '14/04/2014'.' '.'01:15 PM');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/evgHB9)

Comment: +1 What was that about "Déjà vue"? lol ;-) if you ever need those accents ;-)

Comment: I just realized I've been spelling that wrong. Oops. :O

Comment: It still gets the point across. I just have a slighter edge ;-) However, the "é" sounds just like the "e's" in "bene" ;-) pretty close. Copy/paste to your heart's content!

Comment: "é" is ALT-130 on your keyboard. "à" is ALT-133 (*just in case*) ;-)

Comment: I actually knew about the é from attempting to spell `resumé` properly ( i now question whether I really am). I have never had a need to type à yet. As you can see I am isolated in my little world.

Comment: Actually, "resumé" takes two "é" => "résumé" ;-) you're not alone though John; I'm here to help!

Comment: I'll teach you French if you teach me more Italian; fair trade lol

Comment: Looks like I'll end up teaching "you" Italian too then! hahahaha! Pas de problème (no problema)

Comment: Soon I'll be as fluent in Italian and French as I am in PHP. Didn't think they offered that at Stack Overflow. =)

Comment: Actually there are forums on SO for those languages, strangely enough. However, I don't want to join the French forums; they're just way too picky for my taste. It's too "Parisian French", "ouh-la-la"!. Nah, I'll stick with my homegrown "français de la maison" *merci beaucoup*.

Comment: Tu parleras le bon français avant longtemps! (You will be speaking French before long) *oui oui*. ;-)

Comment: From what I understand the French are very particular about their language. They even have some sort of "authority" that oversees it and attempts to keep it "pure". I recall their being an effort in recent years to keep some newer words out because they were seen as un-pure.

Comment: That's only a small majority of groups in the French-speaking sectors and governments in Canada. However, the actual "French" in France; yes and big time. I'm not a purist per se, but I don't appreciate the way that many of today's younger generation are literally tearing such a beautiful language apart.

Comment: Seems like the the younger generation always is pushing things too far> I bet our parents' generation said the same thing about us.

Comment: That's usually how things get started and the cycle never gets broken.